# Wordpress Custom Dashboard Fields

Tags: wordpress

I'm about to use a google maps api for some very specific google maps locational stuff and so the first thing I need to do is allow the user of my website to add the locations into the back end of the locations page.

I have made a quick mockup to show you this what I'm after here:
http://benjaminpotter.org/app.png

Do you know a custom fields plugin that will allow the user to add more fields to the box? ie the "add new location" button to add a new row of entering fields?

Now I would use MapPress but I need to enable searching functionality and Mappress doesn't allow that. So I therefore have to make it myself.

I hope this is clear - thank you for your help in this!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [RW_Meta_Box library](https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box): It got dozens of different field types for custom meta boxes.

If you're intending to make a dashboard widget out of it: It won't work as it binds to the post-new.php and the post-edit.php screen.